# having problem to add background image in html

Tags: css, laravel-blade

I searched everywhere but can't find any solution.Background image is not appearing.My code is written below.I have tried everything but failed.can anyone help me please?

`````
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

 <!DOCTYPE html>
   < html>

  < head>

   < title>fullscreen image background

   < /title>
   < style>

       html{ 

           background:url('fee.jpg')no-repeat center center fixed;
           -webkit-background-size:cover;
           -moz-background-size:cover;
           -o-background-size:cover;
           background-size:cover;

       }
       body{
           color: #FFFFFF;

       }

   </style>

  </head>
  <body>
  <p style="text-align: center;">This is a fullscreen background </p>
  </body>
  </html> 

@endsection````
`````

Comment: Check your web browsers console and see if there are any errors being reported.

Comment: Probably a path issue as usual.

Comment: I did check. There seems to be no porblem.

Comment: which engine is that ?

Comment: I am using sublime text editor and laravel

Comment: @TapuDas Sorry, i meant the template engine, it seems like it's the  
 [`blade`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade) would you mind include the `layouts.app` ?

Comment: One more thing, Try with a picture from the web see if the problem is with the path.

Comment: I tried with another picture.Now there blinks with the image but next second image is  gone again

Comment: try change path with something online ex. `https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/img/jobs/bg-remote-header-sm.png`

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the spaces you put between `<` and the tag names. So remove all the spaces and it will work.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that not only the head tag but all of them. :)

Answer (score 0):

When i paste your code in my local side(sublime) i see spacing problem.you put extra space in html,head,title,title close and style tag i.e < html>(do not do that).so due to what it does not take html tag format. so it does not work.remove that space.

try this it work:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

  <head>

   <title>fullscreen image background

   </title>
   <style>

       html{ 

           background:url('fee.jpg')no-repeat center center fixed;
           -webkit-background-size:cover;
           -moz-background-size:cover;
           -o-background-size:cover;
           background-size:cover;

       }
       body{
           color: #FFFFFF;

       }

   </style>

  </head>
  <body>
  <p style="text-align: center;">This is a fullscreen background </p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

thank you

Comment: I have deleted the extra space but still it does not work

Answer (score 0):

try background-image:url("fee.jpg");